# RSA Algorithm decryption trouble

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, rsa

All new code at the bottom, I re-did the assignment in python, but I am still getting overflow errors. I used the code sections that were given in our assignment and they seem to work fine, but when I am decrypting the private key (variable d) by the standard formula [message = decoded number^private key mod (public key)], or in terms of the variables below, `message = pow(decoded, d) % n`. Is there a way around the overflow that I am experiencing? I imagine that real encryption is happening with python that involves much larger keys, so what can be done differently?

The Assignment (in full):

> We have enlisted your help to decode an intercepted message sent from Bob to his coworker Irene. We know Irene's public RSA key is (n = 111851429, e = 73997). Encoded messages we have cracked between these two in the past use an unconventional scheme, and we expect the same scheme to be used here. There is no random padding used. Each line is padded at the end until its length is an integer multiple of the plaintext block size and then encrypted.
>
> The usual plaintext block size is 4 characters, which they always map to a ciphertext block of 5 characters, so sometimes there are spaces at the beginning of a decrypted block that you have to discard. They encrypt using the ASCII alphanumeric characters, such that a space (ASCII code 032) maps to 0, "!" (ASCII code 033) maps to 1, and so on through "~" (ASCII code 126) mapping to 94. Most programming languages implement a function to map a character to its ASCII code. In VBA it is Asc(). In Python it's ord().
>
> The corresponding functions to map back are Chr() and chr(). So to encode and decode blocks, you might use the following code (in Python, which can be rewritten in whatever programming language you use):

```
from math import *
BLOCK_SIZE = 4

def block_encode(x):
    output = 0
    j = len(x)
    for i in range(j):
        k = ord(x[i]) - 32
        output = output + k*pow(95,j-i-1)
    return int(output)

def block_decode(x):
    output = ""
    i = BLOCK_SIZE+1
    while i > 0:
       b1 = int(pow(95,i-1))
       y = int(x/b1)
       i = i - 1
       x = x - y*b1
       output = output + chr(y+32)
    return output
```

> Your program can either factor n and recover the plaintext directly, or employ a guessing scheme to try various values of d until it recovers the hidden message.
>
> It's highly likely that the word "the" appears in the first line of the plaintext, so if you attack the ciphertext by brute force you can just discard any solutions that don't contain "the." Decrypt at least the first line of the message, so that we can tell what the code says.

The first line of the encoded message is: (with a leading space character)

```
FWfk ?0oQ!#|eO Wgny 1>a^ 80*^!(l{4! 3lL qj'b!.9#'!/s2_
```

My new program, written in python this time:

```
from math import *

BLOCK_SIZE = 4
message = list(" FWfk ?0oQ!#|eO Wgny 1>a^ 80*^!(l{4! 3lL qj'b!.9#'!/s2_")

n = 111851429 #given in problem
p = 5689; #prime of n
q = 19661 #prime of n
e = 73997 #given in problem
z = 111826080 # (q-1)*(p-1)
d = 59107013 # found by (d*e)%z = 1

##########################################

def block_encode(x):
    output = 0
    j = len(x)
    for i in range(j):
        k = ord(x[i]) - 32
        output = output + k*pow(95,j-i-1)
    return int(output)

def block_decode(x):
    output = ""
    i = BLOCK_SIZE+1
    while i > 0:
       b1 = int(pow(95,i-1))
       y = int(x/b1)
       i = i - 1
       x = x - y*b1
       output = output + chr(y+32)
    return output

##########################################

print("Encoded Message: ")
for i in message:
    print(i, end=' ')

print()

i = 0
j = BLOCK_SIZE+1
block = ''

while i< len(message):
    block = ''
    for k in range(i,j):
        block = block+ message[k]
    decoded = block_encode(block)
    decoded = (pow(decoded,d))%n    #This is where it overflows
    print(decoded)
    i = i + BLOCK_SIZE + 1
    j = j + BLOCK_SIZE + 1
```

Comment: You've written your c++ like you expect it to behave just like python. c++ ints are typically 32-bits in size, and integer overflow is silent (and deadly for this assignment). The line `int f = (g^d) % n;` is not going to work. Firstly, '^' is the XOR operator, not exponentiation. c++ doesn't have an exponentiation operator. You'll have to write your own custom exponentiation method. If you can do this assignment in python (or Java with its BigInteger type) you will have much less code to write.

Comment: I concur, if you're fluent in C++, for sure, go for C++. If not please choose a language that has object level support for big integers at the minimum. If C doesn't haunt you like it does me, you can use OpenSSL BN library as well.

Comment: I redid the assignment in python, but now I am getting overflow errors in python. I am not as fluent in python as C++ (if you would even call me that in C++).

Comment: I'd use the three argument version of `pow` in python. `m = pow(c, d, n)`.

Comment: CodesInChaos, you got it! Thank you very much. If you put that as a solution I'll close this thread. Thank you GregS and owlstead for your help as well, I really appreciate it!